# How to set Emacs's ESS R's library folder?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

1. I was using RStudio for my project
2. I'm trying out EMACS+ESS as an IDE since it can also serve as latex/python IDE
3. previously i installed R packages in D (because they take up chunk of HDD)
4. **when i started ESS the R buffer only recognized the R library in C**
5. when i started R.exe from C and used library() it recognized the library in D

**EDIT**
apparently i can use `.libPaths("d:/libpathhere")` to add a libpath
but if i restarted the emacs i found that i need to run this command again to add the libpath again

from the above, it seems the R run in the ESS stored its profile in a place different with R run from C:\program files

**Another Question**
1. how to make R-ESS autoload my R project folder on start
2. how to permanently store the setting of that other libpath in D drive in ESS's R so that it stays recognized after restarting emacs

Comment: For 2. add `.libPaths("d:/libpathhere")` to a file called `.Rprofile` in your home directory. http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html. For 1. do you want R to source all files on start? I'm not sure what you mean by "autoload my R project folder"

Comment: (1) i mean my workspace folder the folder that contain r.data and r.history

Comment: It should load `.RData` by default. When you start R with `M-x R` make sure the starting data directory (in the minibuffer) is your project directory

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.libPaths("d:/libpathhere")` to a file called `.Rprofile` in your home directory. The trick on Windows is to identify where that is.

After starting R within Emacs, the [R for Windows FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What-are-HOME-and-working-directories_003f) suggests running `Sys.getenv('R_USER')` to identify where R thinks the home directory is. That directory is typically `C:\Users\username\Documents`.

Now, you could put your `.Rprofile` file there, but that's not my preference. I set the environment variable `R_PROFILE_USER` in Windows to `c:\Users\username\.Rprofile`, or one could also set it in your Emacs init: `(setenv "R_PROFILE_USER" "c:\\Users\\username\\.Rprofile")`. The [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/Startup) has more details on how R starts.